# How to get CMake's C/C++ compiler commands used when the variables aren't set?

Tags: cmake

CMake can use `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` / `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`,
however in newer version of CMake don't set these variables in the `CMakeCache.txt`.

In the case where the variables aren't set - is there a way to access the C/C++ commands CMake will use for invoking the compiler for a project?

By this I mean what the C/C++ paths that CMake uses to invoke the compilers.

---

*Asking because I wrote a tool that scans the output of a make dry-run, which needs to know the compiler command used to compile source files.*

Comment: What do you mean by "command"? `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`  should specifiy the compiler, but  flags, for example, you can specify by `SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-O2 -O3 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")`.  [May be it can help](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Compilers_and_Tools) Write more information, what you want to do.

Comment: @Sklert, I'm just asking about the compiler command eg: `/usr/bin/cc`, not the flags, thats why I didn't mention flags. Clarified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways (1)(2), you could even think of not scanning but directly output whatever you need to e.g. a file (3).

1. Transferring the variables to the cache

   ```
   set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
   ```
2. Don't look at `CMakeCache.txt`, but at the file where the compiler identification results are stored:

   ```
   CMakeFilse/${CMAKE_VERSION}/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
   ```
3. Output it to `stdout` or a file:

   ```
   message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER = ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")

   file(WRITE "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER.txt" "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
   ```